npm warn deprecated read-package-json@7.0.1: This package is no longer supported. Please use @npmcli/package-json instead
I'm facing this issue while creating new angular app for college assignments:
 npm warn deprecated read-package-json@7.0.1: This package is no longer supported. Please use @npmcli/package-json instead.

changed 237 packages in 39s

44 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

Steps I have taken:

I reinstall the node to the latest version. current node version - v20.13.1
Updated the package.json using - npm install --save @npmcli/package-json
Tried to switch the project working directory.
I restarted the pc multiple time.

How can I resolve this issue? Also suggest any other ways to create the angular app except angular-cli.

That's a warning, not an error. You should be fine working with that warning. What @angular/cli version are you using? If you are using the latest version, v17.3.8, try reinstalling v1.3.7. I just upgraded to v17.3.8 and received the same warning.

Yeah , I should be working with warning but it does not create any files/folders and thats weird. The directory is empty their is not even a single file in that dir

Did you try instaling @angular/cli v17.3.7 instead of v17.3.8?

While I applaud your thoroughness I should point out this is a warning, not an error, and you should still be able to complete a school assignment without fixing it...

I was running into the same issue as you - here are the commands I used to successfully create a new ng17 app:
create an empty dir
install a slightly older version within that dir i.e.
npm install @angular/cli@17.2.3
then run ng new xxxxwhatever

I used that command to run and executed successfully with no warnings and errors. But it should generate files/folders it does not generated any files/folders

I am facing similar issues with Angular 17 as well. But it is not coming when I am installing Angular 18.
In addition to this, I was getting error like "command not found: ng"
So irrespective of whether the warn comes or not, you can run the following command in terminal:
export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"

and then it should work fine, and you should be able to use all ng commands after that.
